# Automated GUI Testing HTML embedded Desktop Application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, desktop-application

I have the exact same problem as in this post [Automated GUI Testing of MFC/Dynamic HTML embedded Desktop Application](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12389/automated-gui-testing-of-mfc-dynamic-html-embedded-desktop-application)

This were an old post but maybe there are new solutions available.

I have written a desktop GUI automation framework with python and winium, but now I have the HTML embedded pages to deal with inside the desktop app, for example fill in forms and submit it.

Can someone please assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Before a couple of months, I did some Desktop automation using Sikuli. Sikuli may be helpful to you

Here I mentioned few Practical Uses of sikuli

- **Using Sikuli we can automate desktop applications.**
- It provides, simple API. i.e. all methods can be accessed using
  screen class object.
- **It can be easily integrated with Selenium and all other tools.**
- Most of the automation testing tools will not support flash object
  automation (E.g. Selenium). Sikuli provides extensive support to
  automate flash objects. It uses powerful “Visual Match” mechanism to
  **automate desktop & flash objects.**

Answer (score 0):

I really like the fact that you have used Winium for automation. Having said that I believe you can go ahead further using selenium to automate the html part of the application. So finally you would be using winium + selenium for the entire application automation and the best part is both implement the same json wire protocol.

FYR - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfyDIz7Mk0U